# Repeated data is being displayed on calendar

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, fullcalendar

I am using fullCalendar JS plugin and i am fetching data in the form of json( in codeigniter ). Data is displaying fine on "Month View" but when i click on "Week view" redundant entry gets appeared. Is it happening because i have used "Datetime" datatype ? Because if i change it to "Date" it does not happen. Also Please tell me , what should i do if i want to display other values than "title" on calendar.
This is my code snippet -

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        selectable: true,
        header: 
        {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek'
        },
        events : "<?php echo base_url()?>secure/fetch_calendar_details",
    });
```

Please help me and Thanks in advance.

Comment: What _"redundant entry"_  are you talking about? can you provide examples of the errors you are receiving? Please provide the PHP code found here `secure/fetch_calendar_details`

Comment: @CodeGodie Redundant entry means if i have one record to display on particular date say 20-7-2015 in a month, it is showing only one record on _Month view_ but when i click on _Week view_, it is showing _two_ records- **one on date-20-7-2015** and **other on date -19-7-2015**. This is the problem means it is _showing redundant entry_ on **Week View**.  **Function** which i am calling _returns_  _JSON_ data is working fine means _it does not return redundant data_.